# Batch file to check programs

Tags: batch-file, cmd, vpn

I am working on a batch file that would need to check if an icon exists on the desktop, if not i want it to check the program folder and if there move it to the desktop. If it isnt installed i want it to run the install file. Can this be done with a batch file if so how?

Answer (score 0):

This is air code:

```
@echo off
if not exist "z:\folder\desktop\iconname.ico" (
if exist "z:\program folder\iconname.ico" (
move "z:\program folder\iconname.ico" "z:\folder\desktop\" >nul
) else (
start "" "c:\backup\program installer.exe"
)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The second condition can be omitted 'cause no other condition exists if icon does not exist in "program folder" so you can try to move it directly without fear if icon does not exist then nothing happens.

Here is the code:

```
@Echo OFF

Set "IconFileName=Icon.ico"
Set "ProgramFolder=%CD%"

if not exist "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%IconFileName%" (
    Move /Y "%ProgramFolder%\%IconFileName%" "%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\%IconFileName%" 2>NUL
) ELSE (
    Start /W "" "%ProgramFolder%\Setup.exe" & REM -Parameters
)

Pause&Exit
```